# Pass Environment variables from Node to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I have an Angular application that is running on a Node environment and as a server is using `express.js`.

This project has to be deployed on a Heroku dyno, so on that platform, to configure the environment, I set the correct one trough a `Procfile` like this:

```
config_env: heroku config:set NODE_ENV=staging
```

Doing this, I have the correct environment set for all the environments.

Now, I would like to pass the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable in some way to Angular so it can read the correct API link that has to be call during the Http requests.

I have already read [this article](https://medium.com/@kudresov/a-better-way-to-inject-environmental-variables-in-angular-d3b2d01a3c5e) that seems to be the only one that has multiple solutions with the final one that, as the writer said, does not have any disadvantages (ok, one, but it is ridiculous).

For me (I am not so experienced in Node neither in Angular) it is not clear how this option 4 is working and maybe a lot of you are now using it, so maybe someone can be clearer than the author.

What I do not understand in particular, is how Angular can understand which environment it has to use.

I explain myself: in the article the author is using Gulp with `gulp-ng-config` to pass the variables (I use Gulp as well so it is very easy to update it with a new task). So, I pass the following `config.json` file to this plugin (similar to the one in [his example](https://github.com/kudresov/angular-config-vars)):

```
{
    "development": {
        "ENV_VARS": {
            "apiUrl": "https://api-development.com/",
            "debug": true
        }
    },
    "testing": {
        "ENV_VARS": {
            "apiUrl": "https://api-testing.com/",
            "debug": true
        }
    },
    "staging": {
        "ENV_VARS": {
            "apiUrl": "https://api-staging.com/",
            "debug": true
        }
    },
    "production": {
        "ENV_VARS": {
            "apiUrl": "https://api-production.com/",
            "debug": false
        }
    }
}
```

And of course I have the following constants as a result:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.constant("development", {"ENV_VARS":{"apiUrl":"https://api-development.com/","debug":true}})
.constant("testing", {"ENV_VARS":{"apiUrl":"https://api-testing.com/","debug":true}})
.constant("staging", {"ENV_VARS":{"apiUrl":"https://api-staging.com/","debug":true}})
.constant("production", {"ENV_VARS":{"apiUrl":"https://api-production.com/","debug":false}});
```

Now the problem remains, because Angular does not know which is the correct environment and then the correct constant that it has to use through the app... So, which is the advantage?

Is there maybe another way where I can pass the `process.env.NODE_ENV` inside the Angular app so I can use something like `$http.get({url: ENV_VARS.apiUrl + 'api/sessions'})` when there are http requests?

Comment: This is a bad practise question. The client (AngularJS) application should know which API endpoint is the right by itself. Just do this by building (distribution) your AngularJS application and parse / replace the config directly inside your AngularJS application e.g. for (dev, test, stage & prod).

Comment: I cannot pass different configuration file because Heroku does not have this feature. I can configure Heroku only when it is building that it has to use a specific environment. This can be done via ```Procfile``` or via ```package.json``` in the ```script node``` of this file (trough the command line that I have wrote at the beginning of the question). For this reason Angular does not know the correct environment.

Comment: This is not depending on your environment (Heroku in your case). It does depend on your application. AngularJS is able to handle a config, so why dont you distribute your application and build it with the config you need? E.g. with grunt or gulp? Check this simple article. https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-configure-your-angularjs-application-using-environment-variables/ In your case `env.js` will be replaced while building your distribution package with the config file you need. Thats all. You can easily handle this with grunt.

Comment: I have already read this article as well, and the problem is always the same: to follow it, you have to upload a config file (the ```env.js``` that you just said) specific for that environment (staging, production, etc) that contains the specific API link. Now, with Heroku this is not possible. Btw, I am already building and compiling the application via Gulp this is why initially I followed the option 4 in the article that I have mentioned in my question (he suggested as a best solution a Gulp plugin). Anyway maybe it is not so clear for me, so can you be more precise about it?

Comment: Also, in a comment of the article that you link, @lin, a guy had the same problem, and he ended up using ```gulp-ng-constant``` that is exactly the same solution proposed in the article that I mentioned in the question...

Comment: I don't get your problem. Why is a deploy of an builded app not possible with heroku? Build your app and deploy it thrue heroku. If you already build your application for an specific env. you just need to deploy it. Could you please explain why this is not possible with heroku?

Comment: You could also deploy your app and build it on heroku. -> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#prerequisites

Comment: Maybe I am not clear when I am writing, but this is actually the problem that I am try to solve with Heroku... The problem is that I cannot upload a config file on it, I can only set the environment at the beginning of the build that is read by Node.js but not by AngularJS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145731/discussion-between-ferie-and-lin).